Changing Row Background Color on Click in MUI (Material-UI)
How can I change the background color of a row when it is clicked without relying on checkboxes in MUI (Material UI)?
What would be the best method to achieve this? I have tried to do different things, however it only seems to work when the checkbox is active (checked).
Here is the code below:
   const handleClickCell = (params) => {
      setSelectedRow(true)

      const selectedRowData =
         dataSearchProduct.productData.currentPageData.find(
            (row) => row.productCode === params.row.productCode
         )

      methods.setValue('productCode', selectedRowData.productCode)
      methods.setValue('productName', selectedRowData.productName)
      methods.setValue('size', selectedRowData.c2PackSize)
      methods.setValue('netAmt', parseFloat(selectedRowData.netAmt).toFixed(2))
      methods.setValue('claimAmount', selectedRowData.claimUsc)
   }

And here is some more code:

  <Box
                  component={'div'}
                  sx={{
                     mt: actionBtnView && 1,
                     height: 420,
                     width: '100%',
                     '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
                        backgroundColor: '#e5e7eb',
                     },
                  }}
               >
                  <DataGrid
                     paginationMode="client"
                     rows={dataTable.content}
                     columns={columns}
                     getRowId={(row) => row.id}
                     initialState={{
                        pagination: {
                           paginationModel: {
                              page: 0,
                              pageSize: pageTableData.pageSize,
                           },
                        },
                     }}
                     rowCount={dataTable.totalCount}
                     sx={{
                        width: '100%',
                     }}
                     checkboxSelection
                     isRowSelectable={(params) => params.row.isSelected}
                     disableRowSelectionOnClick
                     onCellClick={handleClickCell}
                  />
               </Box>

